# Subscription is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I implemented a react-native app, it runs ok.
But 'Subscription is not defined' error happened when enabling 'Debug js remotely' in the simulator.
[image]

Comment: Please add [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bug with Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1711). Try using version 2.2.15 rather than 2.3.0:

`yarn add realm@2.2.15`

Answer (score 8):

Something's wrong with realm. This workaround allows you to run the debugger normally.

`<projectRoot>/node_modules/realm/lib/browser/index.js:150` :

```
...
const Sync = {
    User,
    Session,
    //Subscription, <- Comment this
};
```

And in `<projectRoot>/node_modules/realm/lib/extensions.js:132` :

```
//Object.defineProperties(realmConstructor.Sync.User.prototype, getOwnPropertyDescriptors(userMethods.instance));
```

Comment: You are right, App works ok when I did it as your description.

Answer (score -1):

I solved the same problem:

```
npm install --save realm@2.2.8
```

and:

```
react-native link
```

The system re-downloaded cocoa and re-compiled the project